# How to calculate a value from two other table columns in my SQL

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me understand how to create a result in a column from adding and subtracting values from two other tables/columns?

I have three tables each with a column named "qty":

```
qty_add,  qty_pull,  qty_current
```

I need "qty_current" to reflect a result from the two other columns.

Erik

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you want to add and subtract, share the sample query you use to fetch the records.

Comment: http://wwwlogicpkg.com/login.htm  (admin/demo)

Comment: I just realized that I need the part_no to be shared among the three tables, because I need the qty update to correspond to the correct part_no.  AUUUGH!  Pulling my hair!

Comment: Share the table schema, we can advice on normalization and correct specs, as well as the correct query.

Comment: I uploaded screen shots.

Comment: I'm trying to reflect the latest inventory qty for each part number from two other tables for adding and pulling inventory.

Comment: What is `count` in `cartons_current` and what exactly do you want to do buddy. You want to keep track of the available cartons for each part number?

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to understand what exactly you want to do from your question but this might give you some direction:

```
SELECT part_no,
       SUM(qty) -
       ( SELECT SUM(qty) FROM cartons_pulled
         WHERE cartons_pulled.part_no = cartons_added.part_no ) AS current_qty
FROM cartons_added
GROUP BY part_no
```